# Error using std::cout

Tags: c++

When I try to print text to the Windows console (in a Console Application) I get
Compiler Error C2679 - Binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' (or there is no acceptable conversion).
The code that generates this error is: (where str_var is any variable of type std::string)

`std::cout << str_var << endl;`

It highlights the first '<<' as the error. Could anybody help with this? I can't figure out why that doesnt work.

Comment: Could you post your entire example code that demonstrates this behaviour?

Comment: are you sure it's an std::string and not std::wstring what you are passing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! problem solved! I reinstalled Visual Studio and now it works. So, it was just a problem with VS, not anything about the code.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you are missing:

```
#include <iostream>
```

Comment: I think it is more likely that he is missing `#include <string>`.

Comment: @Karl: if he was missing string, the compiler wouldn't know to complain about 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'.

Comment: I am using a header file, and I have #include <iostream> in that header file. Should I add another #include <iostream> in the .cpp file as well as the .h file?

Comment: I'm assuming you included your header in the .cpp? If so, then you dont need to include again. It would help more if you post more of your code on here.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure string library is included and try

`std::cout << str_var << std::endl ;`

Comment: the string library is included, but not really used. BTW, it throws that error with any type of data, even string constants and integers